How I can to import my sqlmi fog in Terraform
How can I import the failover group of my sqlmi to manage it from Terraform?
We have created it from outside our IaC and now we need it to be managed from Terraform so that everything is integrated correctly.
I have been running the following commands but all with errors:

terraform import 'module.sql_mi["eastus"].azurerm_mssql_managed_instance_failover_group.failovergroup[0]' '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/sqlmi-pro-001/instanceFailoverGroups/fog-eastus?locations=eastus'

Error: ID was missing the locations element

terraform import 'module.sql_mi["eastus"].azurerm_mssql_managed_instance_failover_group.failovergroup[0]' '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/sqlmi-pro-001/instanceFailoverGroups/fog-eastus'

Error: ID was missing the locations element

terraform import 'module.sql_mi["eastus"].azurerm_mssql_managed_instance_failover_group.failovergroup[0]' '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/sqlmi-pro-001/instanceFailoverGroups/fog-eastus?locations=eastus'

Error: parsing "/subscriptions/*****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/sqlmi-pro-001/instanceFailoverGroups" as an ManagedInstanceFailoverGroup ID: the number of path segments is not divisible by 2 in "subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/sqlmi-pro-001/instanceFailoverGroups"
Is it possible to import this type of resource? If import is possible how can I import my fog?
Thank you!

Based on the docs for import, it seems you need a literal locations element: /subscriptions/12345678-1234-9876-4563-123456789012/resourceGroups/resGroup1/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/Location/instanceFailoverGroups/failoverGroup1.

I just tested it and it seems to have worked..
I'm going to take the opportunity to ask you the questions I have:
I don't understand why if it is a SQLMI we don't use a resource id like /providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/sqlmi-pro-001/instanceFailoverGroups/fog-eastus and we must to use
/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/eastus/instanceFailoverGroups/fog-eastus
Would there be any way to see the resurgence id of my fog?
Thank you so much.

The way import works is defined in the resource Go code, i.e, that's how the Azure provider specifies the imports for the particular resource.


Importing my sqlmi fog in Terraform

Thanks Marko E for the valuable inputs you provided as per the MSDoc the correct format to import the resource.
In the command you're sharing location specified was at the end of the ID where it should be as specified in between as mentioned Instance Failover Groups - Failover MS-Doc.
New updated Import command to that should work as below should be in the format
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/{location}/instanceFailoverGroups/{failoverGroupName}

and the command should be like in this format
terraform import 'module.sql_mi["eastus"].azurerm_mssql_managed_instance_failover_group.failovergroup[0]' '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/rg-pro-eastus/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/eastus/instanceFailoverGroups/fog-eastus'

This should work and expected to import the resource as expected.
Note: Make sure the parameters you passed should be matched with the configuration you mentioned in the terraform.
Coming to the query mentioned in the comments different resources possess different resource IDs which include necessary path segments to uniquely identify. The format which I shared above is used in the cases where you're accessing the resources across different regions.
Reference:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PacketFabric/packetfabric/latest/docs/guides/importing
azurerm_mssql_failover_group | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
